Split big CSV file and multithread upload with low footprint
I'm trying to split big CSV files into smaller files and send them to azure storage account, all at the same.
I pretty much read the big file (source) record by record and write it to a temp local file.
When the number of records hits a certain limit, I forcibly flush the writer, close it, dispose it, so that I can continue reading the source and write to a new one.
While going towards the new file, I want to start sending the generated temp file over the internet.
Objective is that I can read/parse source and upload the batched files as quickly as possible while having the minimum possible footprint on memory and disk.
My current code looks like this
public async Task HandleEventAsync(EntityEventMessage message)
{
    var executionGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var uri = new Uri(message.MessageLocation);
    var containerName = uri.Segments[1].TrimEnd('/');
    var blobName = string.Join("", uri.Segments[2..]);
    var entityName = message.EntityName;
    var blobFinalFileName = uri.Segments[^1].TrimEnd('/');

    var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(uri, _tokenCredential);
    var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    var sourceBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    var blobExists = await sourceBlobClient.ExistsAsync();
    if (!blobExists)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("The message of the event does not exist. It might have been processed already.");
        throw new NoRetryException();
    }

    var fileCounter = 1;
    var totalRecords = 0;
    SetUpBatchNames(executionGuid, blobFinalFileName, fileCounter, out var batchFileName, out var tempFilePath);
    var tasks = new Queue<Task>();
    var processTimer = new Stopwatch();
    var options = new BlobUploadOptions
    {
        TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
        {
            // Set the maximum number of workers that 
            // may be used in a parallel transfer.
            MaximumConcurrency = 2
        }
    };

    processTimer.Start();

    using var sourceBlobStream = await sourceBlobClient.OpenReadAsync();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(tempFilePath, true, Encoding.UTF8);
    try
    {
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(sourceBlobStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        using var csvParser = new CsvParser(streamReader, _csvConfiguration);

        var batchTimer = new Stopwatch();
        batchTimer.Start();

        while (await csvParser.ReadAsync())
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(csvParser.RawRecord);
            totalRecords++;

            if (totalRecords % _options.Value.RecordsPerFile == 0)
            {
                fileCounter = await PrepareBatchAndUpload(blobName, blobFinalFileName, blobContainerClient, options, fileCounter, batchFileName, tempFilePath, tasks, writer, batchTimer);

                // Prepare for new batch
                SetUpBatchNames(executionGuid, blobFinalFileName, fileCounter, out batchFileName, out tempFilePath);
                writer = new StreamWriter(tempFilePath, true, Encoding.UTF8);
                batchTimer.Restart();
            }
        }

        if (totalRecords % _options.Value.RecordsPerFile != 0)
            await PrepareBatchAndUpload(blobName, blobFinalFileName, blobContainerClient, options, fileCounter, batchFileName, tempFilePath, tasks, writer, batchTimer);

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        processTimer.Stop();
        _logger.LogDebug("Took '{TotalSplitTimeMs}' ms to split the original file with '{OriginalTotalRecords}' records.", processTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds, totalRecords);

    }
    finally
    {
        writer?.Dispose();

        // Ensure no temp file is left behind
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetTempPath());
        var fileNamesToDelete = blobFinalFileName.Replace(".csv", $"_{executionGuid}_*.csv");
        foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles(fileNamesToDelete))
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
    }

    GC.Collect();

    static void SetUpBatchNames(Guid executionGuid, string blobFinalFileName, int fileCounter, out string batchFileName, out string tempFilePath)
    {
        batchFileName = blobFinalFileName.Replace(".csv", $"_{executionGuid}_{fileCounter}.csv");
        tempFilePath = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{batchFileName}";
    }

    async Task<int> PrepareBatchAndUpload(string blobName, string blobFinalFileName, BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient, BlobUploadOptions options, int fileCounter, string? batchFileName, string? tempFilePath, Queue<Task> tasks, StreamWriter writer, Stopwatch batchTimer)
    {
        batchTimer.Stop();
        _logger.LogDebug($"Took '{batchTimer.Elapsed}' to parse the batch.");
        _logger.LogDebug($"Creating temp file '{tempFilePath}'.");
        await writer.FlushAsync();
        writer.Close();
        await writer.DisposeAsync();

        // Ensure batch file is in same (virtual)folder as the source
        var batchBlobName = blobName.Replace(blobFinalFileName, batchFileName);
        tasks.Enqueue(UploadBatchFileAsync(batchBlobName, tempFilePath, blobContainerClient, options));
        fileCounter++;
        return fileCounter;
    }
}

private async Task UploadBatchFileAsync(string blobName, string filePath, BlobContainerClient containerClient, BlobUploadOptions options)
{
    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    _logger.LogDebug($"Uploading blob: '{blobClient.Uri}'.");

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, options);
    }

    _logger.LogDebug($"Blob uploaded: '{blobClient.Uri}'.");

    //If I do not put Task.Run, delete does not happen after the upload.
    await Task.Run(() => File.Delete(filePath));
}

I have tried multiple things like

plain List().Add(UploadBatchFileAsync(...)) + await Task.WhenAll
make UploadBatchFile sync and have a threadpool to run multiple (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem)
follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN
Task.Factory.StartNew
Tinkle with BlobUploadOptions.TransferOptions.MaximumConcurrency

In general I would either not get the "parallel" behavior I desire or see the performance of the csv reader/writer get impacted.
My current "solution" has some impact on the read/write where normally takes 45s for each 100k lines but it goes up to ~60s.
I understand that at some point, and since im doing local debug, my local pc processes can have some impact, but I'm failing to understand what is really the best way and something tells me I should be able to achieve better overall performance or at the very least, upload the files without affecting the read/write.

If the goal is to improve performance, have you done any profiling? I would expect well written code to be bandwidth limited, so I would not expect much benefit from parallelization of the upload.

Why are you trying to split in the first place? How big is big? It matters a LOT - you won't get any improvement if your network is slow. Blob files can be uploaded in chunks and recombined already. The TransferManager class already uploads data concurrently

Check the upload example in the Data Movement library

The Upload Actions docs show how to upload to staging blocks. You can open multiple read-only streams on the same file and upload different chunks to staging blokcs

@JonasH concurrency does improve performance, which is why download managers allow concurrent downloading or uploading. Individual connections can be throttled by ISPs, firewalls and routers. Uploading in chunks also allows retrying single chunks in case of error without restarting the entire file.

@PanagiotisKanavos, first and foremost, thank you for replying.
I did not try block uploading as I was trying to run away for such details.
I did not try the Data Movement Lib, but fore sure will check it out to see the diff, so thank you very much for this.

@JonasH, I'm afraid this is a "area" i'm not very comfortable, but I did use it to understand I was having a big memory footprint and then look for ways to improve that. I will see if I can learn more on how to check better.

You typically want to stream data, i.e. read some small chunk of data and them immediately upload it, possibly using separate threads for reading and writing. I.e. see Magnus answer.

Compressed text is roughly 10-20% of the original. CSV. XML.

Instead of writing to a local file and than trying to upload that file as a separate task while parsing the rest of the file you can write directly to the blob in the storage account:
await using var blobStream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(overwrite: true);
await using var writer = new StreamWriter(blobStream);
await writer.WriteLineAsync(csvParser.RawRecord);
...

It would make the solution much more simple and you don't need to parallelize it.

Would this not mean I could not parse the source file at the same time?

Maybe you dont need to. Another option is to create X tasks each responsible for a range of rows in the source file.

That i can not do because we are talking about a csv and 1 record != 1 line.

Range of records...

I would I achieve this? Since I can not say if 1 record is 1 row I can not tell the program to fetch x records (maybe im missing something in the Csvhelper). In any case, I more and less try to do that by putting the 100k range into a file and ask another thread to deal with it.
